# Providing access from a Container App to an ACR in a different resource group

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to give the system identity of my container app access to the acr which is deployed in a different resource group. I'm using the Azure CLI in a release pipeline. The service connection I'm using should be scoped to all the resource groups within my subscription. Now for some reason I keep getting the following error message:

```
The client 'xxxx' with object id 'xxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

I'm trying to assign the client which is provided in the error message the role of User Access Administrator because I read that is what it needs, but I'm a bit lost here.

Does anyone know how I should tackle this?

Comment: I'm curious, what are you trying to do? Why do you need to access ACR from an app?

Comment: I'm writing a PowerShell script which deploys my Container App using a release pipeline for each of my environments. My ACR is deployed in my development resource group. When I try to deploy my Container App in my production resource group it needs to be able to pull the image from the ACR, but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant your System Identity specific roles as specified in the documentation.

The available roles for a container registry include:

AcrPull: pull
AcrPush: pull and push
Owner: pull, push, and assign roles to other users

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#service-principal

You could also enable the admin user/password as a test. This is not recommended for production usage but will help you troubleshoot your issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#admin-account

Comment: I tried that using "az role assignment create" where I'm providing the object ID of the system identity of the Container App and the resource ID of the ACR as the scope, but I'm getting "does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope" as the error. When I do the same action using the development Container App it does work however. Just not when I try it from my production Container App.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to make it work. I had to give the service principal of my service connection the User Access Management role in order to let the pipeline run successfully.